# js regexp нужно написать регулярку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужна регулярка на эти символы /^[A-Za-z0-9-*#\s]+$/ и еще чтобы внутри текст было слово one, то есть если мы ввели asdas123 - регулярка пока ругается, но когда мы введе asdas123one, то все ок, причем это слово one может быть хоть в начале6 хоть в конце, по сути можно было бы проверить на. includes, но мне еще нужно чтобы никаких других символов в поле не было, кроме /^[A-Za-z0-9-*#\s]+$/ и слова one, то есть если написать asdas123one - то все ок, а если написать asdas123oneАБВГд то сразу ошибка

Comment: Очень путаное объяснение. Добавьте наглядные тестовые случаи.

Comment: в общем я ввожу в поле asdas match выдает false дальше я добавля слово one - asdasone - match выдает true, но если я добавлю символы, которых нет в  /^[A-Za-z0-9-#\s]+$/  например русские буквы, то  match  выдает false, то есть строка обязательно должна содержат слово one, но при этом она может содержать другие символы, которые указаны здесь  /^[A-Za-z0-9-#\s]+$/ и должна ругаться на символы, которых здесь нет /^[A-Za-z0-9-#\s]+$/, например русские буквы или знак вопроса

Comment: Допускается ли просто "one" без других символов?

Comment: да допускается)

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*one[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*$` - попробуйте так

Comment: Вариант с позитивным просмотром вперед `^(?=.*one)[A-Za-z0-9-#\s]+$`. [Демо](https://regex101.com/r/Ba6VMP/1)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*one[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*$/
```

Подробности

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*` - ноль и более символов, означающих буквы, цифры, `-`, `#` и пробельные символы
- `one` - подстрока `one`
- `[A-Za-z0-9\-#\s]*` - ноль и более символов, означающих буквы, цифры, `-`, `#` и пробельные символы
- `$` - конец строки.